# Proper usage of Group by in Inner Join

Tags: postgresql, group-by

**EDIT** I updated my question with a SQL Fiddle Sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d88b/1

I'm currently making a report from a database records but I don't know how my query should look like, first of all I have 2 tables. Application Forms, and a table for Login Hours of each user

```
forms
->id
->agent_id
->SomeInfo
->created_at


loginhours
->id
->user_id
->loginhours (decimal)
->created_at
```

And I have report with the following columns

```
UserID, TotalLoginHours, TotalApplication, Application Per Hour (aph), Revenue Per Hour (rph)
```

So right now I have this query

```
SELECT a.agent_id, SUM(b.loginhours) as TotalLoginHours, COUNT(a.id) as TotalApplication, SUM(b.loginhours) / COUNT(a.id) as ApplicationPerHour,   (SUM(b.loginhours) / COUNT(a.id)) * 1.75 as RPH 
FROM forms a 
INNER JOIN loginhours b ON a.agent_id = b.user_id WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17' 
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

Note that `user_id` and `agent_id` is the same.

I want to get the result based on the date selected, example `2015-07-17` I got results but my problem is the `loginhours` is being `SUM` based on the number of application for each user. So for example the `user1` has 2 records on `forms` table and his `loginhours` from `2015-07-17` is `2` then in my result the `loginhours` becomes `4` which is wrong, I think it is on my `GROUP BY` statement. Can you help me how to properly query this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query for per agent per day with user name.

Re-frame the Query as per your user table.

```
    SELECT
        A.agent_id,
        users.NAME,
        A.created_at,
        SUM (TotalLoginHours) AS TotalLoginHours,
        COUNT (A.ID) AS TotalApplication,
        SUM (TotalLoginHours) / COUNT (A.ID) AS ApplicationPerHour,
        (
            SUM (TotalLoginHours) / COUNT (A.ID)
        ) * 1.75 AS RPH
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                A.agent_id,
                A.ID,
                A.created_at,
                SUM (b.loginhours) AS TotalLoginHours
            FROM
                forms A
            INNER JOIN loginhours b ON A.agent_id = b.user_id
            WHERE
                A.created_at >= '2015-07-10'
            GROUP BY
                A.agent_id,
                A.ID,
                A.created_at
        ) A
    INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = A.agent_id
    GROUP BY
        A.agent_id,
        users.user_id,
        A.created_at
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir, but can you SUM(loginhours) with date specified? like 2015-07-17. I need the login hours to be sum up for each user on the date specified like 2015-07-17

Comment: Yes, if you are looking for results for each agent per date, then you can do group by agent_id, created_at and remove it from the filter criteria

Comment: Sorry I'm new to SQL, how should that look like in your given query?

Comment: I just modified the answer. Check that

Comment: Sir, ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:         A.created_at SUM(TotalLoginHours) AS TotalLoginHours...

Comment: That was comma missing, Sorry for that. But should have figured out yourself.

Comment: It worked. Sorry. But one last thing, How can I INNER JOIN it to my users table and link it to a.user_id? I know the basic but with that syntax I'm lost. Thanks. If users table has an alias of a, I need a.name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25967/discussion-between-aneesh-mon-n-and-joene-floresca).

Comment: Where's the chat? Can you pm me? thanks

Comment: Check the updated Query

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the multiplication effect you are experiencing, you can do the aggregation first, and then join:

```
select a.agent_id, a.TotalApplication, b.TotalLoginHours
     , b.TotalLoginHours / a.TotalApplication as ApplicationPerHour
     , 1.75 * b.TotalLoginHours / a.TotalApplication as RPH
from (
    SELECT a.agent_id as agent_id
         , COUNT(a.id) as TotalApplication
    FROM forms a
    WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17' 
    GROUP BY a.agent_id
 ) as a
 join (
     select b.user_id as agent_id
          , SUM(b.loginhours) as TotalLoginHours
     from loginhours b 
     group by b.user_id
 ) as b 
     ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id
 ;
```

Not sure I got all the details right, but it should give you a hint of a technique that can be used. I modified your fiddle in: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d88b/9

Comment: Hi thanks for helping. I like your query it's much shorter, I also made a query which returns same result as yours but much longer and I dunno if it is a good practice, take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d88b/10 Then tell if it is ok or not then why? If not I'll use yours and accepts it as answer. thanks

Comment: updated it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d88b/11

Comment: I see someone else answered your question so I'll just comment on your query in the fiddle. The basic problem with your query is that you are repeating the same calculation over and over again. A sufficiently smart optimizer could in theory detect this and rewrite it for you, but I don't think we are there just yet. Common Table Expressions (CTE) might come in handy in such situations, I suggest you have a look at that in the documentation